# How to overcome limit of tokens in for loop in windows script

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

I have a list and I need to get the last element from this list.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...............35
```

I am iterating using a for loop i.e. using the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=" %%A
```

Now in a for loop token is limited up to 31. How to overcome this in a windows batch script file?

Answer (score 0):

```
call :lasttoken 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39

echo %last_token%

goto :eof

:lasttoken

if not "%2" == "" shift && goto :lasttoken

set last_token=%1

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal 
set "mylist=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"
set "mylist=%mylist% 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40"
:: so far we've only set up the program and established the list.

for %%a in (%mylist%) do set "value=%%a"

echo last value in %mylist% is %value%
```

...but now I see a necromancer has been at work. Still, work done so I may as well publish it.

Works in this somewhat artificial circumstance. May be better methods depending on the real situation.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the last token and will work for extremely long lines where batch fails.

```
type "file.txt" | repl ".* (.*)" "$1" >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.